# PivotField NumberFormat not being applied via VBA although it works manually

Tags: excel, vba, number-formatting

PivotTable fields (measures) loose their formatting when removed from the pivot table. You have to re-format them after adding them back to the pivot table. I'm using Excel 2019, PowerPivot with datamodel inside the Excel.

I need formatting which includes different colors for `+-0`. This is the formatting: `[Color10]0,00%;[Red]-0,00%;[Black]-` (Color10 is a correct coded color in Excel for number formattting)

I'm trying to set up a macro which shall do that. I've recorded a macro. When the macro is run, it "invents" its own formatting and does not apply the one I gave it to do.

So, after the code is run, the numberformat applied is `[Color10]#.000%;[Red]-#.000%;[Black]-` instead of `[Color10]0,00%;[Red]-0,00%;[Black]-`. Note that when I apply this desired formatting manually - it stays as such.

It seems the issue is not related to the PivotTables or powerpivot itself. The same issue appears when trying to do

```
ActiveSheet.Range("F1").NumberFormat = "[Color10]0,00%;[Red]-0,00%;[Black]-"
```

**It works** if I apply desired formatting to a cell manually, and then apply the formatting from **that** cell to the pivottable field like this:

```
.PivotFields("[Measures].[M To Market vs IMS Volume %]").NumberFormat = ActiveSheet.Range("F1").NumberFormat
```

What am I missing?

Other non-macro options which I tried:

- This is NOT supported within Excel data model (colors!)
- This is not supported with DAX format function (colors!)
- Using manual formatting of cells even with setting pivottable property to preserve cell formatting on update doesn't preserve it when you change the fields in the pivot table.
- Same thing if you try ConditionalFormatting

Macro options which I tried:

- on pivottable update even for the worksheet - Excel regularly crashes (it calls the procedure like 30 times if I leave on error resume next; it throws an error otherwise and crashes.)
- I've deleted the "ghost" custom formatting, tried again, and Excel seemed to recreate that custom formatting that I did not wanted.
- I've searched for potential escape characters for `%` sign in VBA string but nothing special came up except for the double quotation marks themselves.

---

```
Sub set_pivottable_number_formatting()

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables(1)
        MsgBox .PivotFields("[Measures].[M To Market vs IMS Volume %]").NumberFormat
        .PivotFields("[Measures].[M To Market vs IMS Volume %]").NumberFormat = "[Color10]0,00%;[Red]-0,00%;[Black]-"

        MsgBox .PivotFields("[Measures].[M To Market vs IMS Volume %]").NumberFormat
    End With

End Sub
```